# Can I create a dynamic 2D array in C like this?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

Can I use

```
size_t m, n;
scanf ("%zu%zu", &m, &n);
int (*a)[n] = (int (*)[n])calloc (m * n, sizeof (int));
```

to create a dynamic 2D array in C, whose size of rows and columns can be modified by function `realloc` during runtime?

Comment: Note: `(int (*)[n])` cast not needed and is distracting.  Consider `int (*a)[n] = calloc(m, sizeof a[0]);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `calloc(m, sizeof a[0]);` is less readable than the OP's code, in my opinion. See [this](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285898/285910#answer-285910).

Comment: What do you mean with "whose size of rows and columns can be modified by function realloc during runtime?" Individually sized rows/columns or a 2D matrix where each row and column has the same size? Depending on what you mean, the code will be very different.

Comment: That's not a 2D array then, but an array of pointers, or "jagged array" if you will.

Comment: What I mean is that all columns are in the same size, but the number of both rows and columns can be changed

Answer (score 0):

This record

```
int (*a)[n] = (int (*)[n])calloc (m * n, sizeof (int));
```

is correct provided that the compiler supports variable length arrays.

It may be written also like

```
int (*a)[n] = calloc ( 1, sizeof ( int[m][n] ) );
```

On the other hand, there is a problem when you will use `realloc` and the number of columns must be changed. This can result in losing elements in the array in its last row because C memory management functions know nothing about types of objects for which the memory is allocated. They just allocate extents of memory of  required sizes.

Otherwise if the compiler does not support variable length arrays you will need to allocate array of pointers and for each pointer an array of integers. This approach is more flexible in sense that you can reallocate separately columns and rows.

Comment: I think this only allows 1 dimension of the array to be modified by `realloc()` during runtime? `n` remains `n` after all.

Comment: @Uduru See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use pointer-to-pointer-to-int and alloc first array for "pointers to lines" and then init all items by allocating memory for "arrays of int".

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    size_t m, n;
    scanf("%zu%zu", &m, &n);
    int **a = (int **)calloc(m, sizeof(int*));
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        a[i] = (int *)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    }
    /// Work with array
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            a[i][j] = i+j;
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Such approach allows to make realloc later

Comment: This is less efficient.

Comment: This is called "jagged array", and is quite a different thing than 2-dimensional array, under the hood and in purpose.

Comment: @hyde I agree with you, but is realloc typical operation for "2-dimensional array" ?

Comment: @VolAnd As typical as for 1-dimensional array, I'd think. It's a bit unclear which the OP wants/needs here, TBH.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I create a dynamic 2D array in C like this?
> `int (*a)[n] = (int (*)[n])calloc (m * n, sizeof (int));`

Yes.

Cleaner as `int (*a)[n] = calloc(m, sizeof a[0]);`

> Can I use `int (*a)[n] = ....` to create a dynamic 2D array in C, whose size of rows and columns can be modified by function realloc during runtime?

No.  Once an array size of `a` is defined, (`n` in this case), the size can not change.

---

Instead consider allocating an array of arrays

```
// Error checking omitted for brevity
int **a2 = malloc(sizeof a2 * rows);
for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  a2[r] = malloc(sizeof a2[0] * cols);
}
```